# Packages that can model effects of intense electric fields from femtosecond compressed IR and EUV laser pulses on surfaces?

Tags: software-recommendations, surfaces, 2d-lattice, optical-properties, finite-difference-time-domain

[Laser-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser-based_angle-resolved_photoemission_spectroscopy#Laser-based_ARPES) and [time-resolved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser-based_angle-resolved_photoemission_spectroscopy#Time-resolved_electron_dynamics) ARPES are *relatively*<sup>1</sup> new techniques to study atomic and especially electronic structure (necessarily) near crystal surfaces and of adsorbed 2D materials on those surfaces.

Pulse compression techniques can produce focused laser pulses with femtosecond-scale duration and small spot sizes, producing enormous electric fields, and [high harmonic generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_harmonic_generation) can simultaneously give the individual photons energies (within a still-coherent, compressed beam) in the 20 to 100 eV range or higher.

**Question:** What are software packages that can model the effects of intense electric fields from femtosecond compressed IR and EUV laser pulses on surfaces?

#### But what does "model the effects" mean?

High individual photon energies alone are not new - synchrotron beams have been used with ARPES for a long time, cf. [X-ray photoelectron spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_photoelectron_spectroscopy) or XPS.

But the nature of the pulse-compressed laser beams is such that the instantaneous electric fields at and just below the surface of the sample are enormous - in the eV per Angstrom regime!

Classically, two dielectric spheres in an electric field will polarize and then attract or apply torque on each other depending on their relative orientations. For quantum mechanical atoms, polarization (displacements of electronic charge wrt nuclear charge) can also happen.

Thus I wonder if these high fields can excite "mechanical" forces on an adsorbed 2D material on a surface, or excite collective phonon phenomenon at the surface of a crystal just for example.

To try to simulate these effects, what packages can address the physics of femtosecond and eV/Angstrom scale transient electric fields on these material systems?

---

<sup>1</sup>compared to synchrotron light sources and helium UV lamps (He Iα & IIα  at 21.2 & 40.8 eV)